# Unomitting a "tio[n]" before a ke-clause

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Take, for example, the following sentences.

> Mi scias, ke la monado kaŝis pilon.
> Mi volas, ke vi ĝin faru.
> Ne estas, ke mi vin ne amas, <blah blah>.

Is there really an invisible, elided "tio[n]" after the verbs in the main clauses, which represent the ke-clauses?

> Mi scias **tion**, ke la monado kaŝis pilon.
> Mi volas **tion**, ke vi ĝin faru.
> Ne estas **tio**, ke mi vin ne amas, sed <blah blah ia senkulpigo>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La teksto enhavas problemetojn, kiuj laŭ mi estigas la demandon:

> Mi scias, ke la monado kaŝis pilon.
>
> Mi volas, ke vi <strike>ĝin</strike> *tion* faru.
>
> Ne estas **...**, ke mi vin ne amas, .

La dua linio devus esti:

```
Mi volas, ke vi tion faru.
```

Komparu kun tiu ĉi frazo (Zamenhof, Fabeloj de Andersen 4):

> Mi tiel forte dezirus, ke ŝi tion faru!

`Ĝi` prenas la lokon de -o vorto: pano, hundo, homo, pilo, sed ne la lokon de `ke ...` frazo.

`Tio` povas ankaŭ preni la lokon de -o vorto, kaj aldone, tiun de `ke ...` frazo.

En la tria linio, izolita subfrazo `Ne estas,` rekte sekvata de `ke ...` aŭdeblas strange. Se temas pri ekzisto, kio ne estas/ekzistas? Se temas pri idento, kiuj estas la du elementoj?

Jen tia frazo de Zamenhof:

> Ne estas grave, ke oni naskiĝis en anasejo

Tie `esti` havas la du elementojn: `grave` kaj la `ke ...` frazon. Se oni skribus:

```
Ne estas, ke oni naskiĝis en anasejo
```

Aperas do la demando: *ne estas kio/kia/kiel?*

En la tria linio, laŭ mi, mankas io, ekzemple:

```
Ne estas pro tio, ke mi vin ne amas, ...
Ne estas vero, ...
Ne estas imageble, ...
```

En la unua linio, la `ke ...` frazo rolas kiel objekto do ne bezonatas *tion*.

Answer (score 1):

PMEG has a chapter [*Ke-frazoj kiel objekto*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/ke/objekto.html), which says that you usually don't need a *tio*. Sometimes you can add to clarify or emphasize. For instance in your third sentence I would say

- *Ne estas tiel, ke mi vin ne amas, sed <blah blah ia senkulpigo>*